# Is there a wildcard format directive for strptime?

Tags: python, time, timezone, strptime

I'm using `strptime` like this:

```
import time
time.strptime("+10:00","+%H:%M")
```

but "+10:00" could also be "-10:00" (timezone offset from UTC) which would break the above command. I could use

```
time.strptime("+10:00"[1:],"%H:%M")
```

but ideally I'd find it more readable to use a wildcard in front of the format code.

Does such a wildcard operator exist for Python's `strptime` / `strftime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no wildcard operator. The [list of format directives](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) supported by `strptime` is in the docs.

What you're looking for is the `%z` format directive, which supports a representation of the timezone of the form `+HHMM` or `-HHMM`. While it has been supported by `datetime.strftime` for some time, it is only supported in `strptime` [starting in Python 3.2](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641).

On Python 2, the best way to handle this is probably to use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), manually handle the negative offset, and get a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
import datetime

tz = "+10:00"

def tz_to_timedelta(tz):
    min = datetime.datetime.strptime('', '')
    try:
        return -(datetime.datetime.strptime(tz,"-%H:%M") - min)
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(tz,"+%H:%M") - min

print tz_to_timedelta(tz)
```

In Python 3.2, remove the `:` and use `%z`:

```
import time
tz = "+10:00"
tz_toconvert = tz[:3] + tz[4:]
tz_struct_time = time.strptime(tz_toconvert, "%z")
```

Answer (score 1):

We developed [datetime-glob](https://libraries.io/pypi/datetime-glob) to parse date/times from a list of files generated by a consistent date/time formatting. From the module's documentation:

```
>>> import datetime_glob
>>> matcher = datetime_glob.Matcher(
                         pattern='/some/path/*%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ.jpg')

>>> matcher.match(path='/some/path/some-text2016-07-03T21-22-23Z.jpg')
datetime_glob.Match(year = 2016, month = 7, day = 3, 
                    hour = 21, minute = 22, second = 23, microsecond = None)

>>> match.as_datetime()
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 3, 21, 22, 23)
```