# Parsing date and timestamps in Python with time.strptime format

Tags: python, time, timezone, strptime

My cloud server logs time in this format:

```
[17/Dec/2011:09:48:49 -0600]
```

To read it into Python variables, I can say:

```
>>>str = '17/Dec/2011:09:48:49 -0600'
>>>import time
>>>print  time.strptime(str,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S -0600")
```

Result:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm-mon=12, tm=mday=17, tm_hour=9, tm_min=48, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=351, tm_isdst=-1)
```

or I can try

```
>>>mytime = time.strptime(str,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S -0600")
>>>print mytime.tm_hour
```

Result:

```
9
```

What does the `-0600` do?  I expected it to adjust the hour value in the date time object?  Is there a wildcard to use instead of hard-coding the `-0600`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `-0600` is the offset from Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).  As [another SO question already says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959778/is-there-a-wildcard-format-directive-for-strptime), time.strptime cannot read timezone offsets, though `datetime.strftime` can generate them.

As explained at the start of [the `datetime` module's documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959778/is-there-a-wildcard-format-directive-for-strptime), there are two ways of approaching "time" in python, naive or aware.  When all you care about is time *inside your system*, dealing with naive time/datetime objects is fine (in which case you can strip out the offset as alan suggested).  When you need to compare the values inside your system with the *real world's notion of time*, you have to start dealing with that offset.

The *easy* way to deal with this is just to [use `python-dateutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).  It has a [parse function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) that will do its best to fuzzily match the date string you pass in to multiple formats and return a workable datetime instance that represents its best guess as to what you meant.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('17/Dec/2011:09:48:49 -0600', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 17, 9, 48, 49, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))
```

Normally, having software give its "best guess" is a Bad Thing.  In this case, it seems justified if your input formats are stable.  Dealing with time in software development is hard, just go shopping.

Comment: Im taking a look at python-dateutil.  Hadn't been aware of it's purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It's the offset from GMT. If you don't want it, just strip it off:

```
>>> import time
>>> line = '17/Dec/2011:09:48:49 -0600'
>>> line = line.split(' ')[0]
>>> print  time.strptime(line,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=17, tm_hour=9, tm_min=48,  tm_sec=49, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=351, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: I like the way you split the date and take the first index all on one line

Comment: it works with regular expressions too: newdate = re.split(" ", myStr)[0]

Answer (score 3):

`strptime` simply matches the modifiers (`%d`,`%b`, ...) with the corresponding segments of the string and then converts that matched piece of string to an integer.  So in your case, the `-0600` only makes it so that your format string matches the input string.

If you want to adjust the time by a specified offset, I would recommend using a `datetime` object.

```
>>>s = '17/Dec/2011:09:48:49 -0600'
>>>from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>>mytime = datetime.strptime(s,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S -0600")
>>>dt = timedelta(minutes=6*60)  #6 hours
>>>mytime-=dt
>>>print mytime
2011-12-17 03:48:49
>>>print mytime.hour
3
```

Also note that since `str` is a builtin, it is generally not advisable to reassign it.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out about using str as a variable name.  Bad habit!

Comment: Here's a link to the format codes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes