# Parse datetime from string in python what can 778 mean?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I need to parse string type value which looks like **017-11-18T05:26:01.778+0000**

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_in_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S-%j-%f")
```

but it gives mistake like

```
ValueError: time data '2017-11-18T05:26:01.778+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d '
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: The patterns don’t match.

Comment: My problem is in correct format which I can't find myself

Comment: It looks like there should be a 'T' between %dT%H...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Answer (score -1):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(date_in_string, fuzzy=True)
```

you have a timezone parameter also in your date, that's the reason of your error

Comment: for further information on parsing these type of dates you can look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298032/parsing-date-and-timestamps-in-python-with-time-strptime-format

Comment: as useful as dateutil might be, there's no reason to use it to answer the question - providing the correct format string would be much more helpful.